# Locally free sheaves is equivalent to a open cover and transition functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I have some questions about locally free sheaves when reading The Rising Sea: Foundation of Algebraic Geometry:

> Given a locally free sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ of rank $n$ on a scheme $X$, we can take an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ such that for each $U_i$, $\phi_i:\mathscr{F}|_{U_i}\cong \mathcal{O}_{U_i}^{\oplus n}$.  Then this open cover determines transition functions $T_{i j}\in GL_n(\mathcal{O}(U_i\cap U_j))$, which satisfy the cocycle condition.  Moreover, this data determines the locally free sheaf.

My question is:

How to show that transition functions determine the locally free sheaf? Clearly $\mathscr{F}$ is equivalent to the data $\{U_i\}$ and $\phi_{i j}:\mathcal{O}_{U_i\cap U_j}^{\oplus n}\cong \mathcal{O}_{U_i\cap U_j}^{\oplus n}$ satisfying the cocycle condition.  And when $U_i\cap U_j $ is affine, $\phi_{i j}:\mathcal{O}_{U_i\cap U_j}^{\oplus n}\cong \mathcal{O}_{U_i\cap U_j}^{\oplus n}$ is equivalent to $\phi_{ij}(U_i\cap U_j)\in GL_n(\mathcal{O}(U_i\cap U_j))$ via quasi-coherence.  But I wonder why they are equivalent in general case.

Comment: A locally free sheaf is certainly quasi-coherent, no? Then you can restrict the transition functions to an affine cover to get a gluing to the sheaf itself.

Comment: @AHappyMathematician In order to gluing up $\mathscr{F_i}$ on $U_i$ to a sheaf of $X$, we need transition functions $\phi_{ij}: \mathscr{F_i}|_{U_i\cap U_j}\cong \mathscr{F_j}|_{U_i\cap U_j}$ satisfying cocycle condition.  And in the case of my question,  we need a sheaf isomorphism $\phi_{i j}$ when restricted to $U_i\cap U_j$.  So I think we can not glue if we restrict the transition function to a smaller open subset of $U_i\cap U_j$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $GL_n$ is affine, a morphism $X \to GL_n$ (for *any* scheme $X$) is the same as a ring map $\Gamma(GL_n, \mathcal{O}_{GL_n}) \to \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$. (See Vakil 7.3.G.)

Since $\Gamma(GL_n, \mathcal{O}_{GL_n}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x_{ij} : 1 \leq i, j \leq n][1/\det]$, this is equivalent to giving an invertible matrix of elements of $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, which in turn is equivalent to an automorphism of the $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n}$ as an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module.